# how to group rows in jquery uisng w2grid?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, w2ui

I'm trying to achieve this format using w2ui grid. I don't know how to group the cells (rows) or split the cells. I tried to split while rendering but couldn't achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 1.5 records can have a `w2ui.colspan` property (of type object).

Rowspan is not supported.

I have not seen this feature in action yet, but let me quote mrg2001, who is a Collaborator of the w2ui project on github:

> Combining with colspan should allow you to achieve this. Colspan example is
>
> ```
> records: [
> { recid: 1, title: "some", w2ui: { colspan: { field: 2 } }
> ...
> ]
> ```

Source: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues/280